# Null Pointer Exception on using HTTPServletRequest.authenticate in Tomcat 7

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I have a servlet based REST API. I have to conditionally turn on/off authentication based on the path parameters. I have the rules stored in the DB.
So I found that servlet3.0 provides HTTPServletRequest.authenticate(), which can be used to programmtically launch a login.
So, I added the following in my web.xml

```
<login-config>
 <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

And in my ServletFilter, I have this code to launch login programmatically

```
request.authenticate(response);
```

But I get a Null Pointer Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.authenticate(Request.java:2603)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.authenticate(RequestFacade.java:1059)
```

Am I missing any configuration? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide some more context on where  `response` is coming from?  It looks like `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.authenticate` is looking at `response.isCommitted()`, which would obviously cause a NPE if `response` is null.

Comment: The response object is from my doFilter method of ServletFiliter

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your ServletFilter to verify that response is non-null when calling authenticate?

Comment: Yes. I checked that response is non-null